What metrics should look when solana agave node starts lagging?
We running several nodes in several data centers and sometimes they lag, but catch up quickly ( in a minute or so ).
We have several solana nodes running on agave v 2.0.18 v 2.0.20.
in different data centers in different providers OVH and LeaseWeb
and they worked OK for long time ( we running solana nodes more than 3 years )
yesterday we observed behavior that all our nodes starting lagging on same time

Servers have plenty of resources, they did not lag before, and the pattern of CPU / IO / LA / Network did not change
In logs we sometimes see messages like:
[2024-12-24T05:17:55.324352022Z WARN  solana_core::warm_quic_cache_service] Failed to warmup QUIC connection to the leader Ey3DkEVbfBxfWmkTsG7Hqj7jshYf5Zx9H8462Zjjkykf, Error Custom("\"ConnectionError(TimedOut)\"")
[2024-12-24T05:25:01.267478163Z WARN  solana_core::warm_quic_cache_service] Failed to warmup QUIC connection to the leader 13xkw4jY5PvZnqCFZSTBQCjHGNd6VTu1A6PHF2rU9AnA, Error Custom("\"ConnectionError(ConnectionClosed(ConnectionClose { error_code: CONNECTION_REFUSED, frame_type: None, reason: b\\\"\\\" }))\"")

Question is: what metrics can we monitor to understand the reason for this lagging?
What can be a reason for this behavior?
